# How to use default if index does not exists

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have the following input:

```
alerts:
  api_http_500:
    default_config:
      enabled: true
    override:
      user_1:
        enabled: false
```

I wanna check if the enabled field exists for a user. If it not so I use the default one.
I'm using [index](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions) and `default` like follow:

`{{ (index $alerts "alerts" "api_http_500" "override" "user_2" "enabled") | default (index $alerts "alerts" "api_http_500" "default_config" "enabled") }}`

But I have this error `<index $alerts "alerts" "user_2" "enabled">: error calling index: index of nil pointer`.

I don't know how to use the default value without a if/else structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fundamental error is that there is no `user_2` field in the data, so when you try to fetch it, you get `nil`; you can't do deeper lookups in that.  `default` can still come to the rescue!

The [Go `text/template` language](https://godoc.org/text/template) supports local variables.  So we can set a local variable to what should be the `user_2` value.  If that's not present, the [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) support library includes a [`dict`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) function that can produce an empty dictionary.

```
{{- $overrides := index $alerts "user_2" | default dict -}}
```

Now `$overrides` is always a dictionary, so we can look up in that, or if there's nothing there, fall back to the defaults.

```
{{- $a := index $alerts.alerts "api_http_500" -}}
{{- $defaults := $a.default_config -}}
{{- $overrides := index $a.override "user_2" | default dict -}}
{{- $enabled := $overrides.enabled | default $defaults.enabled -}}
```

This looks good, but the one other problem is that `default` doesn't distinguish present-but-false from absent; both are "falsey" and will get replaced with the default value.  The standard template `eq` requires values to have the same type, but Sprig's [`deepEqual`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/reflection.html) doesn't have this requirement.

This lets you write the detailed logical statement that the option should be enabled if the override is true, or if the override is not false (I don't think there's a way to spell out "nil" or "absent") and the default is true.

```
{{- $enabled := or $overrides.enabled (and (not (deepEqual $overrides.enabled false)) $defaults.enabled) -}}
```

(It is worth considering whether you want this much Go template logic, and whether you can either restructure your values file to simplify this, or use something like a Kubernetes operator that's in a more normal language and is more testable.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `index` approach you can also use the "round brackets approach".

So instead of:

```
{{- $a := index $alerts.alerts "api_http_500" -}}
{{- $defaults := $a.default_config -}}
{{- $overrides := index $a.override "user_2" | default dict -}}
```

You can write:

```
{{- $defaults  := (($alerts.alerts).api_http_500).default_config    | default someDict    -}}
{{- $overrides := ((($alerts.alerts).api_http_500).override).user_2 | default otherDict -}}
```

In many cases it brings a much cleaner code where the **validation for null and the value retrieval is achieved without extra logic** (like the addition of `index` function or extra assignment of variables).